# Should we merge the verse tag into poetry?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Right now, [verse](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verse) has 5 questions, while [poetry](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) has 2.  I don't really see a difference or a need for two tags, so I was thinking I'd merge them both into [poetry](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry).  But I thought I'd ask on meta first.

Any objections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go for it!

[filler text for the Stack Exchange spam filter]